# Call by value-return with void function

Tags: evaluation-strategies

If I'm passing parameters as call by value-return and call a void function, will the local values within the function still be copied to the corresponding values in the caller function even though the called function doesn't return? For example:

```
int x = 4;

void foo(int a) {
    a = 8 + 8;
}

int main() {
    foo(x);
    print x;
}
```

Will the value printed be 4 or 16? My hunch is that because foo never returns, the local value for a within the stack frame of foo never gets copied back to the value for x in the stack frame for main, but I wanted to double check.

Comment: Why do you think `foo()` never returns?

Comment: Of course, this will depend a bit on the language/compiler implementation (and specification); but if void functions are allowed, the returning has to be implemented in some sensible way, implicitely without a return statement.

Comment: @Maxpm ohhh wait it just implicitly returns nothing, right?

Comment: This is a question about the C programming language, and so off-topic here. I suggest running the program and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It will print 4 because sending by value will change the copy not the original variable which is x in your example.

Comment: The question is about [call by value return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_copy-restore), not call by value. Does that change your answer?